# Ubuntu only recognizes 1 audio jack out of two

Tags: sound, microphone, audio-jack

I have an Alienware M14x, as the title sais i have two audio jack but only one works when I plug the earphones. Also mi mic jack doesn’t work either. what can i do to activate them or make Ubuntu aware that they exist

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the `/etc/modprobe.d/alienware-audio-fix.conf` file

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/alienware-audio-fix.conf
```

and adding the following:

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-eq
```

It's lets the sound driver know what type of computer you are using (when autodetection fails).